# How to calculate the number of same elements in 2D arrays in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, sum, checksum

Now I have two 2D arrays, I want to compare

`['A','B','E','G', 'T']` & `['A','C','E','N','M']`
`['a','f','c','h','u']` & `['a','b','c','y','l']`

and calculate the same elements.

```
aaa = [['A','B','E','G','T'],['a','f','c','h','u']]
bbb = [['A','C','E','N','M'],['a','b','c','y','l']]
```

So in this example, the output is 2+2

I know how to do if it's a 1D array, but don't know how to do this with 2D arrays. Many thanks.

Comment: These are lists though

Comment: I've already edited my title, don't know why it's still on hold..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `zip()` builtin method to pair elements:

```
aaa = [['A','B','E','G','T'],['a','f','c','h','u']]
bbb = [['A','C','E','N','M'],['a','b','c','y','l']]

c = sum(ii[0] == ii[1] for i in zip(aaa, bbb) for ii in zip(*i))
print(c)
```

Prints:

```
4
```

EDIT: If you don't care about order of elements, you can use sets:

```
aaa = [['A','E','C','G','T'], ['a','f','c','h','u']]
bbb = [['A','C','E','N','M'], ['a','b','c','y','l']]

c = sum(len(set(i1) & set(i2)) for i1, i2 in zip(aaa, bbb))
print(c)
```

Prints (Common elements in first array 'A', 'E', 'C' and in second array 'a', 'c'):

```
5
```

Comment: Hi Andrej, what if I don't care about the order of the elements, just sum the mutual elements? For instance, aaa = [['A','E','C','G','T'], bbb = [['A','C','E','N','M'], there are three mutual elements, but the output is not 3

Comment: @Cecilia See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.chain` to flatten lists of lists, and use `zip` to pair elements of those flattened lists.

```
from itertools import chain

aaa = [['A','B','E','G','T'], ['a','f','c','h','u']]
bbb = [['A','C','E','N','M'], ['a','b','c','y','l']]

c = sum(a == b for a, b in zip(chain(*aaa), chain(*bbb)))
```

EDIT: With this method, you might want to be careful that `aaa` and `bbb` have the same dimensions because the following code will produce the same result as above.

```
from itertools import chain

aaa = [['A','B','E','G'], ['T','a','f','c','h','u']]
bbb = [['A','C','E','N','M','a'], ['b','c','y','l']]

c = sum(a == b for a, b in zip(chain(*aaa), chain(*bbb)))
```